# Remove the sorting options from the Telerik RadGrid context header menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, contextmenu, radgrid

I have a Telerik RadGrid that use the header context menu for filtering propose. I would like to remove the sorting and grouping options from the menu using a client side function.

I was able intercept the open menu calling the **OnClientShowing** method.
[image]

I made something similar for removing some options for the columns submenu.

```
function OnClientItemOpening(menu, args) {
             var item = args.get_item();
             item.get_items().getItem(0).get_element().style.display = "none";
             item.get_items().getItem(1).get_element().style.display = "none";

         }
```

I want to keep the sorting and grouping functions outside the context menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it like this:

```
<HeaderContextMenu OnClientShowing="removeDuplicadedOp"/>
```

js function

```
function removeDuplicadedOp(menu, args) {             
  //menu.get_items().getItem(0).disable();
  menu.get_items().getItem(0).get_element().style.display = "none";

}
```